# Bash:How to group multiple street addresses together with the same state?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to use either awk, grep, or sed to group a bunch of street addresses together, organize the name first, the city second, and group them on the left-justified side by their state.

Here is the data

```
Mickey Mouse, 1111 Disney Dr., Orlando FL
Minnie Mouse, 1112 Disney Dr., Anaheim CA
Adam Voter, 902 Biscayne Blvd., Miami FL
Zelda Boscso, 4000 State St., Chicago IL
Susie Green, 799 15th St., Indianapolis IN
Tom Furter, 800 N. Walsh St., Milwaukee WI
Dave Ile, 111 W. Illinois Ave., Madison WI
Sam Karter, 1400 E. 57th St., Los Angels CA
Howard Messer, 5957 W. 157th St., Orland Park IL
Ogden Nash, 2800 S. Lake St., Berkeley IL
Penelope Ogden, 1527 W. Aurora Rd., Naperville IL
Harvey Pelican, 800 N. Lake SHore Dr. #134, Michigan City IN
Tawanda Rice, 1027 Belmont Place, West Palm Beach FL
Kendall Smith, 2231 W. 13th St., Madison WI
Byron Trapp, 5 S. Maple Dr., Indianapolis IN
Dominique Daniels, 771 W. 77th Ct., Gary IN
Gandalf Addison, 200 Palm Drive, Jupiter FL
Jenilee Harrison, 511 River Rd., San Francisco CA 
Waylon Jetson, 111 Skyway Dr., Green Bay WI
Gollum Zeller, 908 Martin Pl., Tampa FL
Vickie Edison, 14251 W. Central, Milwaukee WI
Milton Callahan, 333 Cordoba Rd., Schamburg IL
```

Here is what the output is supposed to look like.

```
CA
Jenilee Harrison, San Francisco
Sam Karter, Los Angeles
Minnie Mouse, Anaheim

FL 
Gandalf Addison, Jupiter
Micky Mouse, Orlando
Tawanda Rice, West Palm Beach
Adam Voter, Miami
Gollum Zeller, Tampa

IL 
Zelda Bosco, Chicago
Milton Callahan, Schaumburg
Howard Messer, Orland Park
Ogden Nash, Berkeley
Penelope Ogden, Naperville

IN
Dominique Daniels, Gary
Susie Green, Indianapolis
Harvey Pelican, Michigan City
Byron Trapp, Indianapolis

WI
Vickie Edison, Milwaukee
Tom Furter, Milwaukee
Dave Ile, Madison
Waylon Jetson, Green Bay
Kendall Smith, Madison
```

Here is my code

```
awk '{print $NF"|"$1,$2,$5,$6}' amazon.txt | sort -t"|" -k1 | awk -F"\" '{print $NF }'
```

Here is my output.

```
Jenilee Harrison, Rd., San
Minnie Mouse, Dr., Anaheim
Sam Karter, 57th St.,
Adam Voter, Blvd., Miami
Gandalf Addison, Drive, Jupiter
```

What am I doing wrong? Do note that some cities have 1 or 2 words in their names.

Comment: Use an array whose keys are the states.

Comment: You need to use `,` as the field separator. Then you need to split the last field using space to separate the city and state.

Comment: @Barmar How do you make an array in Bash when there are a variable number of states?

Comment: The array should be in `awk`, not `bash`. `a[state] = a[state] "\n" $1 ", " city`

Comment: Do you have to do this in Bash?  Why not just do this in Python?  More maintainable, testable, extensible, etc?

Comment: @AmirAfghani It doesn't have to be Bash but I prefer to use either basic Linux, Bash, or Perl plus awk/grep/sed. Complex programming languages like Python or Java are outside of the scope of the course I am taking.

Comment: @Peabodyjr. : A bash array is not of fixed size. Hence it does not matter whether you know the number of elements in advance. In your case, you could have an associative array (like a Perl Hash) where the key is a state abbreviation. BTW, if you do the whole thing in Perl, you certainly need any awk/grep/sed anymore. Another possibility would be to go for Zsh, which has IMO more features which can attract programmers. You could also go for Ruby, which I find even less complex than Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=", " }
{
  sub(/ +$/,"")
  match($NF,/.* +/)
  city=substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +$/,"",city)
  district=substr($NF,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  cityArr[district]=(cityArr[district]?cityArr[district] ORS:"")($1 OFS city)
}
END{
  for(i in cityArr){
    print  i ORS cityArr[i]
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=", " }                       ##Setting field separator and output field separator as comma space here.
{
  sub(/ +$/,"")                            ##Substitute spaces at last of line with NULL here, to remove them from output.
  match($NF,/.* +/)                        ##Using match function to match everything till last occurrence of spaces in last field.
  city=substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH)          ##Creating city variable which has sub string starting from RSTART to RLENGTH(where RSTART and RLENGTH are default variables of awk)
  sub(/ +$/,"",city)                       ##Substituting last occurring spaces in variable city.
  district=substr($NF,RSTART+RLENGTH)      ##Creating variable district, which has the last value in line.
  cityArr[district]=(cityArr[district]?cityArr[district] ORS:"")($1 OFS city)  ##Creating cityArr(array) which has index 
  ##as district and keep appending 1st field and value of city in this array with same indexes here.
}
END{                                       ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i in cityArr){                       ##Traversing through cityArr here.
    print  i ORS cityArr[i]                ##Printing index with new line and value of cityArr here.
  }
}' Input_file                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Also your shown samples are having spaces at end of line to remove them I have taken care of that too in this solution.

---

---

***EDIT:*** To print a new line after each district value just added a bit logic in above solution.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=", " }
{
  sub(/ +$/,"")
  match($NF,/.* +/)
  city=substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +$/,"",city)
  district=substr($NF,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  cityArr[district]=(cityArr[district]?cityArr[district] ORS:"")($1 OFS city)
}
END{
  for(i in cityArr){
    if(++count>1){ print "" }
    print  i ORS cityArr[i]
  }
}' Input_file
```

Comment: Works like a charm! The only minor problem is that there is supposed to be a newline between the final entry of a state and the next state initial. That is a minor issue that even I could probably fix though.

Comment: @Peabodyjr., your welcome. You could probably change your `cityArr[i]` in `END` block of this code to `cityArr[i] ORS` and it should print a new line but only thing you will get an extra line at last of output here, cheers.

Comment: @Peabodyjr., ok I have added an EDIT solution, please check it once, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(.*),.*,(.*) (\S\S).*/\3\n\1,\2/ # reduce and re-arrange record
        H                                  # append to hold space
        x                                  # swap to hold space
        s/(\n..)(\n.*)\1(\n.*)/\1\3\2/     # group by state
        x                                  # swap back to pattern space
        $!d                                # delete all but last 
        x                                  # swap to hold space again
        s/.//' file                        # remove starting newline and print
```

To format the file in sorted order and  a space line between states, use:

```
sed -E 's/(.*),.*,(.*) (\S\S).*/\3 \1,\2/' file |
sort -k1,1 -k3,4r |
sed -E 's/(..) (.*)/\1\n\2/
        H
        x
        s/(\n..)(\n.*)\1(\n.*)/\1\3\2/
        x
        $!d
        x
        s/\n..\n/\n&/g
        s/..//'
```